# Why am I getting 401 unauthorized when issuing a post request with axios, but the same request works with postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-401

I working with Odoo and I have bought a module that allows setting APIs that enables third-party applications to communicate with it.
On that basis, I am trying to implement a Reactjs web app that will commune with odoo, fetch the data with "axios" and so on.
So I trusted testing the APIs with postman and everything seemed to be working, but when it came to actual implementation on react, I got several errors and problems such as CORS and the one that I mentioned on the title 'Why am I getting 401 unauthorized when issuing a post request with axios, but the same request works with postman':

So the API that I am trying to get to work is this one

'/api/authentication/oauth2/token'

it works fine in postman with the following configuration:

[image: Postman configuration and response]

But when getting to react with the following piece of code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
console.log('Je suis pas');
const oauth = require('axios-oauth-client');

const getClientCredentials = oauth.client(axios.create(), {
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8070/api/authentication/oauth2/token',
grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  client_id: '5lTtYE1SYw9mdbOhB8JgInJrlFxwqI',
  client_secret:'WaiPFle1kn7wjBAVjOV2etx8KK3nmL',
response_type:'code',
scopes:'all',


});

const auth = await getClientCredentials();

console.log('auth')
console.log(auth)}
```

I get the following error

[image: post request error with axios]

Comment: What about headers? I can see that you are sending 15 headers while making the request through Postman but none through axios.

Comment: @AbhijayKumar i din't send any with postman, they are pre-configured and hidden headers

Comment: Hello. I am having a similar issue. Do you have an update on your question? Were you able to resolve it?